# Django: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Games'

Tags: python, django

I have a model named `Games` with some fields, I'm trying to query 2 latest games & 2 random games in a single variable from the database.

Here's what I tried,

```
data1 = Games.objects.order_by('-id')[:2]

data2 = sorted(Games.objects.exclude(id__in=data1), key=lambda x: random.random())[:2]
```

But now I'm stuck, I couldn't combine the games present in `data1` & `data2` variables into a single variable `data3`.

Here's what I tried,

```
data3 = Games.objects.filter(Q(id__in=data1) | Q(id__in=data2))
```

But it's raising an error, `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Games'`.

How can we do that? Thank You :)

Comment: can you add your Games model to the question?

Comment: @Azsgy Sir, Games model simply contains a `charfield`, `textfield`, `slugfield` & `filefield`

Comment: Can't you able to compine `list(chain` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon I tried chain but that didn't work. Answer given by Sir `Rakesh` is working fine :) Please let me know if there is any other method too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data3 = Games.objects.filter(
    reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(id__contains=i.id) for i in data1]) |
    reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [Q(id__contains=i.id) for i in data2])
    )
```

Comment: Sir, is it possible with `list(chain()` method too?

Comment: I am not sure what the `list(chain())` method is?

Comment: I tried chain method, something like `chain( Q(Games.objects.filter(id__in=data1)) | Q(Games.objects.filter(id__in=data2)) )` but that didn't work.